# GGPlot 2 columns, only some stacked

Tags: r, ggplot2

I currently have a geom_col graph with columns not stacked (using position_dodge2), that looks like this:

[image]

but I'm trying to duplicate a graph that was originally created in excel that looks like this:

[image]

Where two of the columns were stacked.  I could obviously not use "position_dodge2" and they'd all stack, but any ideas how I can do that to just two of the columns?

Also please let me know if this has been asked elsewhere or if you'd like me to include reproducible data. I didn't include the data from the below graphs as it has protected information in it.

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30021410/ggplot2-side-by-side-barplot-with-one-bar-stacked-and-the-other-not) may be an exact duplicate.

Comment: Other possibly useful info in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43282244/2461552) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40641416/2461552)