# Combine dodge and stack position in the same bar graph with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I need to represent some data in a very specific way. Right now I have a factor "treatment" with 8 levels, and then for each level, 4 different values obtained in the experiment (let's call it "type" factor with levels c("a", "b", "c", "d"). I would like to represent a graph where I have all "treatment" levels with position dodge for "type" "a" and "b", and then I would like to stack "c" and "d" together.

I've tried to implement [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43282244/9480256) with no success.

What I have
[image]

What I want
[image]

I'm pretty sure it's not gonna be possible to have it exactly like I need, but I can accept a close enough try.

Thanks!
J.

Comment: Hi there. When you say you haven't had success with the linked solution, what hasn't worked? What does your code look like? If you can post a reproducible example that would be useful.

Comment: Hi @Megan, maybe "tried to implement" wasn't the right choice of words. To be honest I don't know where to start. I just thought that code could help me, but the case here is different. In his case, one of the mutants only has one of the levels of the factor and I think that's how he is able to separate. I don't really know how to apply it here.

Comment: Having looked at the answer, I don't think it is that only one of each bars is stacked, it's that the x axis is numeric that differs critically from yours by the sounds of it. There might be answers that can help you here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12715635/ggplot2-bar-plot-with-both-stack-and-dodge. However I don't think it is part of the functionality, you have to use workarounds really.